# MCMC sampling using deterministic transformation

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

There are two random variables $X,Y$ with deterministic non-linear surjective and non-injective relationship $y=f(x)$ and I know unnormalized pdf $\hat{p}_y(y)$.
I want to obtain samples $y \sim p(y)$, but I want to perform sampling in the space of $X$.
The theory says that I have to use variable transformation $p(y)dy = p(x)dx$, and use $p(f(x))\mathrm{det}(\frac{df}{dx})$ as a sampling objective in MCMC. But will it work with non-injective $f$, for example $f = x^2$?

And in general, are there any ways to get rid of the determinant of the Jacobean using MCMC?

Comment: If $f$ is not injective, the Jacobean formula does not hold. If there are only a finite number of possible antecedents $x$ for a value $y=f(x)$, the function can be turned into a bijection by [making a rule for] selecting one antecedent. If $f^{-1}(y)$ is a continuous set, an arbitrary distribution can be chosen over that set, but the appeal of simulating $X$ instead of $Y$ is much less clear.

Comment: @Xi'an , yep, you are right. I will delete my comment as incorrect. Thanks

Comment: @Xi'an, thank you for your comment. In my case, both $X,Y$ are continuous. But can you clarify your point about the arbitrary distribution? In the end I want to have a distribution $p(x)$ such that $ x \sim p(x)$ gives $f(x) \sim p(y)$.

Comment: If $p_Y$ is given, if $f$ is not injective, and if one is looking for $p_X$ such that $p_Y=f_\sharp p_X$, there is an indeterminacy over each $f^{-1}(y)$ that is not a unit set/singleton. Take for instance $f(x)=x^2$ that requires setting weights on $\sqrt{y}$ and $-\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: It remains unclear to me why one would want to create $p_X$ to simulate $X$ and then transforming it by $f$.

Comment: I have a Bayesian Neural Network and I try to force its output distribution to have some particular shape. So I need to find such distribution of weights ($X$ in the previous example), that will give a desired $p(y)$, where $y$ is an output of the BNN.